# Entity Framework 4 issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Using .NET Web API (.NET 4, EF 4) and I'm getting some strange errors when debugging and really can't figure what is going on.

Say in the `DocumentRepository` I have this constructor:

```
public DocumentRepository(DocPortalContext db)
{
    this._db = db;
}
```

If I debug and hover over `_db` and drill into the items in the popup window I'm coming across the following errors:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext = 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and

> System.Collections.Generic.ICollection>.IsReadOnly = 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

*No exceptions are being caught.*

If I put a break point on this line in a repository method - `return  _db.Documents.AsQueryable();` - and hover over `Document` I get the following error:

> System.Linq.IQueryable.Provider = 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery' could be f...

Some help would be much appreciated.

**Additional information:**

Drilling into `_db` in the following way gives message quoted at the end:

> base(System.Data.Entity.DbContext) -> Internal Context -> _appConfig -> and finally Default Connection Factory has the following error beside it "The function evaluated requires all threads to run."

**More information as per my comment:**

This isn't really related to the question, but it has me thinking there could be something wrong with my install of .NET or VS - I don't know enough about the pipework to make that call, maybe one of you can. Anyway, I can browse to a URI in my WebAPI project and get JSON returned in the browser. When I try to consume the URI in my Website project, I get this in my browser: `Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\System.Net.Http.StreamContent'.` which is also caught as an exception.

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq` in the header of the class?

Comment: Yes it's being referenced.

Comment: Yes, this is odd, because these look like compiler errors, not runtime errors.  Try doing a clean and rebuild.  Maybe something is out of whack between the pdb's and your code causing a problem during debug.

Comment: Just did a clean and rebuild and same errors when debugging.

Comment: It's odd that you get this when debugging - the compiler should catch this, so you shouldn't be able to run it in the first place. Can you show us where `_db` is defined?

Comment: `_db` is defined in the repository: `private DocPortalContext _db;` and is disposed of properly. Going to add some more info to the question now.

Comment: Just did another clean and rebuild and restarted VS. Browsed to the URI and I'm getting JSON returned to my browser. Debugged to double check there's no errors, but there is as described in question...

Comment: Try this on the repository method you mentioned above do return _db.CreateObjectSet<Document>().AsQueryable<Document>();

Comment: Are you referencing System.Data.Entity or EntityFramework?

Comment: This isn't really related to the question, but it has me thinking there could be something wrong with my install of .NET or VS - I don't know enough about the pipework to make that call - maybe one of you can. Anyway, I can browse to a URI in my WebAPI project and get JSON returned in the browser. When I try to consume the URI in my Website project, I get this in my browser: `Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\System.Net.Http.StreamContent'.` which is also caught as an exception. Anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' does not contain a definition for 'System' <-- Maybe you have an entity called System in your context?

Answer (score 1):

By default EF 4 generates proxy classes on the fly that inherit from your POCO classes or your model first classes. That is most likely why you get these errors on runtime. The odd things is that all required usings should be included.

Are you sure you reference System in your POCO classes (presuming you have POCO classes)?

Comment: There's an existing database and I'm writing POCOs based on those tables, at the moment only one. I'm almost certain `System` is being referenced. I can't be totally sure though until I'm in work. This was all working originally, I had a generic repository which I took out and this is when the problems began.

Comment: Yeah that is likely because otherwise many things wouldn't be working. Also make sure you have the EF NuGet package installed everywhere that you use your classes. Just to be sure. That's all I can think of right now :-).

Answer (score 1):

Do all projects in your solution have the same .NET version setup in project's properties?
Do those versions agree with the version on the MSDN describing the missing classes?

Answer (score 1):

Try registering your `entity-framework` dll and `sql-server` dll in global assembly cache using `gacutil.exe` from visual studio command prompt

Answer (score 1):

I had come across this issue recently on a small sample application where we just included nuget packages and created some data layer objects. This is what we did and it solved the issue

1. Make sure temp folders for .net are clean . usually in asp.net temporary files in windows directory.
2. Make sure your visual studio is upto date and not requiring a restart due to nuget reinstall. Not sure if it solved or did help but i checked this as well and restarted vs.
3. Clean the projects and made sure that dlls are present. if you are using some webmatrix dll for asp.net simple membership make sure you have selected to copy it locally. This was one issue when we were seeding data for roles and members for mvc4 simple membership use but may not be the case for your project.
4. We also checked that in web projects the configuration for ef corresponds to proper version of ef.

Build the solution and run it after a vs 2012 restart and it worked fine. Now I dont know exactly which of these things helped in resolving this issue but doing all 4 worked in one case.

Just thought to share if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

These look like issues relating to an incompatibility between your project's target .Net version and the build version of the assembly you're referencing.

In this instance, you should make sure that the assembly you are referencing is less than or equal to your project's target .Net Framework version.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this message numerous times. 9 times out of ten, this means that there is a likely problem with the App.config file. Usually, it is just missing. In other words, for every project folder you have referencing the Entity Model you need to place a copy of that App.config file within it. If they are already there, then delete the App.config file that partners the edmx file, and recompile the Entity Model separately to regenerate it. (DON'T DELETE THE EDMX FILE or THE DESIGNER CLASS) Then you have to replace all the App.config's again.  Yes, it sucks!!!  Sometimes, LinqPad is great for checking this issue too. You can reference the dll file in LinqPad and attempt to run queries giving you the same error message letting you know that the problem is not just Visual Studio.

Hope this helps...Good Luck!!!!

Answer (score 0):

How are you implementing your repository? Seems to me that maybe the problem is that your application is running on a different thread than your repository and that might be the answer for the "The function evaluated requires all threads to run." message.